# Hello There Calculator

Tags: c#, calculator, community-challenge, antlr, dsl

The open source project I work on uses Antlr4 pretty heavily, but I don't know much about it. I thought I would use [April's Community Challenge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5174/april-2015-community-challenge) as an opportunity to learn something about grammars, lexers, and parsers.

My calculator only handles integer multiplication, division, addition, and subtraction, but it does handle the order of operations correctly. Whitespace is stripped away, so it's optional, and the calculator will throw an `ArgumentException` if it's passed an expression that it doesn't understand.

Is there anything I could have done better? I do think I want to go back and add support for exponentiation and parenthesis later, but that's later.

[**GitHub repo here.**](https://github.com/ckuhn203/Antlr4Calculator/tree/a2c9aad350e6ea46b1e51e4158185910cfb212e0)

**BasicMathGrammar.g4**

```
grammar BasicMath;

/*
 * Parser Rules
 */

compileUnit : expression+ EOF;

expression :
    expression MULTIPLY expression #Multiplication
    | expression DIVIDE expression #Division
    | expression ADD expression #Addition
    | expression SUBTRACT expression #Subtraction
    | NUMBER #Number
    ; 

/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */

NUMBER : INT; //Leave room to extend what kind of math we can do.

INT : ('0'..'9')+;
MULTIPLY : '*';
DIVIDE : '/';
SUBTRACT : '-';
ADD : '+';

WS : [ \t\r\n] -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

**IntegerMathVisitor.cs**

```
class IntegerMathVisitor : BasicMathBaseVisitor<int>
{
    public override int VisitCompileUnit(BasicMathParser.CompileUnitContext context)
    {
        // There can only ever be one expression in a compileUnit. The other node is EOF.
        return Visit(context.expression(0));
    }

    public override int VisitNumber(BasicMathParser.NumberContext context)
    {
        return int.Parse(context.GetText());
    }

    public override int VisitAddition(BasicMathParser.AdditionContext context)
    {
        var left = WalkLeft(context);
        var right = WalkRight(context);

        return left + right;
    }

    public override int VisitSubtraction(BasicMathParser.SubtractionContext context)
    {
        var left = WalkLeft(context);
        var right = WalkRight(context);

        return left - right;
    }

    public override int VisitMultiplication(BasicMathParser.MultiplicationContext context)
    {
        var left = WalkLeft(context);
        var right = WalkRight(context);

        return left * right;
    }

    public override int VisitDivision(BasicMathParser.DivisionContext context)
    {
        var left = WalkLeft(context);
        var right = WalkRight(context);

        return left / right;
    }

    private int WalkLeft(BasicMathParser.ExpressionContext context)
    {
        return Visit(context.GetRuleContext<BasicMathParser.ExpressionContext>(0));
    }

    private int WalkRight(BasicMathParser.ExpressionContext context)
    {
        return Visit(context.GetRuleContext<BasicMathParser.ExpressionContext>(1));
    }
```

**ThrowExceptionErrorListener.cs** [*(This lets me throw exceptions on bad input.*)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29834489/3198973)

```
class ThrowExceptionErrorListener : BaseErrorListener, IAntlrErrorListener<int>
{
    //BaseErrorListener implementation
    public override void SyntaxError(IRecognizer recognizer, IToken offendingSymbol, int line, int charPositionInLine, string msg, RecognitionException e)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Expression: {0}", msg, e);
    }

    //IAntlrErrorListener<int> implementation
    public void SyntaxError(IRecognizer recognizer, int offendingSymbol, int line, int charPositionInLine, string msg, RecognitionException e)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Expression: {0}", msg, e);
    }
}
```

**Calculator.cs**

```
public static class Calculator
{
    public static int Evaluate(string expression)
    {
        var lexer = new BasicMathLexer(new AntlrInputStream(expression));
        lexer.RemoveErrorListeners();
        lexer.AddErrorListener(new ThrowExceptionErrorListener());

        var tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        var parser = new BasicMathParser(tokens);

        var tree = parser.compileUnit();

        var visitor = new IntegerMathVisitor();

        return visitor.Visit(tree);
    }
}
```

**Unit Tests**

```
[TestClass]
public class EvaluateTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void OrderedOperation()
    {
        var expr = "1 + 6 - 2 * 3 / 2";
        // 2 * 3 = 6
        // 6 / 2 = 3
        // 1 + 6 = 7
        // 7 - 3 = 4
        Assert.AreEqual(4, Calculator.Evaluate(expr));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
    public void BadInput()
    {
        var expr = "1 + 5 + 2(3)";
        int value = Calculator.Evaluate(expr);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SimpleAddition()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(2, Calculator.Evaluate("1 + 1"));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void RepeatedAddition()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(10, Calculator.Evaluate("1 + 2 + 3 + 4"));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SimpleSubtraction()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(2, Calculator.Evaluate("4 - 2"));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void RepeatedSubtraction()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(5, Calculator.Evaluate("10 - 3 - 2"));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SimpleMultiplication()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(4, Calculator.Evaluate("2 * 2"));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void RepeatedMultiplication()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(8, Calculator.Evaluate("2 * 2 * 2"));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SimpleDivision()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(2, Calculator.Evaluate("4 / 2"));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void RepeatedDivision()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(2, Calculator.Evaluate("8 / 2 / 2"));
    }
}
```

Comment: "Hello There Calculator", really? That's your title? I would have expected something much better from you, ducky!

Comment: Best I could do @SimonAndréForsberg. It was my "Hello World" ANTLR project. Feel free to change it if you've got something better.

Comment: [Discussion continues in this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23172/discussion-between-rubberduck-and-bart-kiers)

Comment: A bit old but, besides the discussion about ANTLR, **(1/2)*3** == **1/(2*3)** and the order of evaluation here doesn't matter.

Comment: Bit late on this one, but I feel the inherant need to point out that [BEDMAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) (order of evaluation) is very important.   In the example [Federico](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/122486/federico) provided, is equivalent to saying `0.5 * 3 == 1 / 6`  which is false.  That is just evaluating the brackets portion as [BEDMAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) requires brackets be evaluated first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a now [deleted answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/87891/41243) by [Bart Kiers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/3008/bart-kiers).

> You've given multiplication a higher precedence than division.
>   Usually, these have the same precedence. I.e., the expression 1 / 2 *
>   3 is usually evaluated as (1 / 2) * 3 (from left to right), which is
>   1.5. But in your case, it will be evaluated as 1 / (2 * 3), which is 0.16666666666.
>
> Also, your NUMBER rule matches the INT rule, meaning that INT could
>   never become a token of its own (it cannot be used inside a parser
>   rule). Whenever this happens, make that rule a fragment (see:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487593/what-does-fragment-means-in-antlr).
>
> You're also probably not trying to match multiple expressions, but
>   rather a single expression. I.e. compileUnit : expression+ EOF; should
>   be compileUnit : expression EOF;.
>
> And ANTLR4 supports more compact character classes. Instead of doing
>   ('0'..'9'), you can use [0-9].
>
> Here is a demo in Java (easily ported to C#) that shows a way to
>   handle operator precedence properly:
>
> ```
> grammar BasicMath;
>
> compileUnit : expression EOF;
>
> expression
>     : expression op=( MULTIPLY | DIVIDE ) expression #mulExpression
>     | expression op=( ADD | SUBTRACT ) expression    #addExpression
>     | '(' expression ')'                             #parensExpression
>     | NUMBER                                         #numberExpression
>     ;
>
> NUMBER : INT;
>
> fragment INT : [0-9]+;
>
> MULTIPLY : '*';
> DIVIDE   : '/';
> SUBTRACT : '-';
> ADD      : '+';
>
> WS : [ \t\r\n] -> channel(HIDDEN);
> ```
>
> And a driver class to test it:
>
> ```
> public class Main {
>
>   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
>     String expression = "1 / 2 * 3";
>     BasicMathLexer lexer = new BasicMathLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(expression));
>     BasicMathParser parser = new BasicMathParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
>     Double value = new IntegerMathVisitor().visit(parser.compileUnit());
>     System.out.println(expression + " = " + value);
>   }
> }
>
> class IntegerMathVisitor extends BasicMathBaseVisitor<Double> {
>
>   @Override
>   public Double visitCompileUnit(@NotNull BasicMathParser.CompileUnitContext ctx) {
>     return this.visit(ctx.expression());
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public Double visitParensExpression(@NotNull BasicMathParser.ParensExpressionContext ctx) {
>     return this.visit(ctx.expression());
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public Double visitMulExpression(@NotNull BasicMathParser.MulExpressionContext ctx) {
>     if (ctx.op.getType() == BasicMathLexer.MULTIPLY) {
>       return super.visit(ctx.expression(0)) * this.visit(ctx.expression(1));
>     } else {
>       return super.visit(ctx.expression(0)) / this.visit(ctx.expression(1));
>     }
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public Double visitAddExpression(@NotNull BasicMathParser.AddExpressionContext ctx) {
>     if (ctx.op.getType() == BasicMathLexer.ADD) {
>       return super.visit(ctx.expression(0)) + this.visit(ctx.expression(1));
>     } else {
>       return super.visit(ctx.expression(0)) - this.visit(ctx.expression(1));
>     }
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public Double visitNumberExpression(@NotNull BasicMathParser.NumberExpressionContext ctx) {
>     return Double.valueOf(ctx.NUMBER().getText());
>   }
> }
> ```

---

Which is all technically spot on and extremely good advice. However, changing `expression+ EOF` to `expression EOF` breaks the visitor, because calling `context.GetText()` "glues" together adjacent tokens that were previously separated by the white space. This results in `1+12-23*3`, with no way to catch the error (to the best of my knowledge), because as far as the parser and lexer are concerned, there is no error. I overcome this issue by leaving the `compileUnit` rule unchanged and checking the number of expressions in my `Calculator` class, and throwing an exception if more than one expression was passed into the evaluate method.

```
var tree = parser.compileUnit();

var exprCount = tree.expression().Count;
if (exprCount > 1)
{
    throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Too many expressions. Only one can be evaluated. {0} expressions were entered.", exprCount));
}

var visitor = new IntegerMathVisitor();

return visitor.Visit(tree);
```

Comment: `context.GetText()` simply gives a string representation of of the start- and end token of said context. It does *not* glue together any token, the parser will treat these tokens separately. I know I won't be able to convince you of this fact OP, but this remark is just for people who stumble upon this incorrect remark. Mat is correct in his last remark in the chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23172/discussion-between-rubberduck-and-bart-kiers

Comment: Right @BartKiers and in this case, the start and end of the context contains two tokens that get smushed together by my Visitor. Now, will you please undelete your answer so that I may give it the checkmark for future visitors?

Comment: Let me rephrase a little bit. The `GetText` method is returning the two consecutive tokens together as one string, when it is sent through `Int.Parse`, it is interpreted as a single number. I understand perfectly well what is going on here @BartKiers, and that is exactly what I describe above. I resent the fact that you imply I don't understand what's happening and you've been totally unwilling to have a civil discussion about it.

Comment: The expression `1+1 2-2 3*3` would trigger syntax errors for the rule `compileUnit : expression EOF;`. If you let ANTLR's default error recovery mechanism handle this, then odd things might happen, obviously. But using `NUMBER` inside a parser rule would *not* result in `1 2` being glued together as one token `12`. I will stop now because you seems to be getting agitated again, and will probably soon be flagging these comments again. Best of luck.

Comment: I've not tried attaching my custom error listener to the parser. Maybe something is getting swallowed there that I'm not aware of. I'll look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

First, I have to mention that I'm [very happy](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3Avba-grammar) that you chose to explore [antlr](/questions/tagged/antlr)! ...looking at what you've done here, you now know more about `Visitor` and `ErrorNode` than I do!

But ANTLR aside...

[Classes are `internal` unless specified otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3763638/1188513); still it would be nice to be explicit about it, and stick that `internal` modifier in front of your `internal` classes.

I don't like the name you've chosen for `ThrowExceptionErrorListener` - it makes the type's name sound like a method, as *throw* is a verb, and class names should be *nouns*. How about `ThrowingErrorListener`?

I'm not sure about this line here:

> ```
> lexer.RemoveErrorListeners();
> ```

You just instantiated it, does it come with error listeners for free? If so, that deserves a comment. If not, then that line could be removed.

Comment: It does come with an error listener "for free" actually. The [ConsoleListener](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/ConsoleErrorListener.java). You're right about leaving a comment there through. As for the name, I'm leaving it unless someone can come up with something better. I don't think `ThrowingErrorListener` is an improvement. It still starts with a verb (ish).

Comment: Well I would have suggested `ExceptionThrowingErrorListener` but that seemed a bit... over-the-top ;)

Comment: I like `ThrownExceptionErrorListener`. Or `SyntaxErrorListener`. Or `ErrorListener`.

Answer (score 4):

You could take a page out of functional programming and shorten the visitors for the multiply, divide, subtract, and add:

```
public override int VisitAddition(BasicMathParser.AdditionContext context)
{
    return VisitHelper(context, (left, right) => left + right);
}

public override int VisitSubtraction(BasicMathParser.SubtractionContext context)
{
    return VisitHelper(context, (left, right) => left - right);
}

public override int VisitMultiplication(BasicMathParser.MultiplicationContext context)
{
    return VisitHelper(context, (left, right) => left * right);
}

public override int VisitDivision(BasicMathParser.DivisionContext context)
{
    return VisitHelper(context, (left, right) => left / right);
}

private int VisitHelper(BasicMathParser.ExpressionContext context, Func<int, int, int> apply)
{
    var left = WalkLeft(context);
    var right = WalkRight(context);

    return apply(left, right);
}
```

And in C# 6 it'll become:

```
public override int VisitAddition(BasicMathParser.AdditionContext context) =>
    VisitHelper(context, (left, right) => left + right);
```

I'm almost alright with not declaring local variables though. The function names are descriptive enough, especially knowing we're traversing a tree:

```
public override int VisitAddition(BasicMathParser.AdditionContext context)
{
    return WalkLeft(context) + WalkRight(context);
}

public override int VisitSubtraction(BasicMathParser.SubtractionContext context)
{
    return WalkLeft(context) - WalkRight(context);
}

public override int VisitMultiplication(BasicMathParser.MultiplicationContext context)
{
    return WalkLeft(context) * WalkRight(context);
}

public override int VisitDivision(BasicMathParser.DivisionContext context)
{
    return WalkLeft(context) / WalkRight(context);
}
```